# Error installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, admob

Hi any one faced this error while installing Admob.

> [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o
>   /var/folders/_r/thfyvgfn1f19wtmqttvwfpxh0000gn/T/d20161213-1890-nik74x/file.tgz
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/b8337da55c97ec54-Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK-7.14.0.tar.gz
>   --create-dirs --netrc-optional
>
> ```
>   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:02 --:--:--     0curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
> ```

**Here is my podfile.**

```
# Pods for admobintegration

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Comment: Hi Mad, I am getting same issue with pod 'Firebase/Core'

Comment: same error in here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wasted 5 hours to reach the solution. Now in my XCode project it work fine.
The issue was because of Ethernet Network Proxy OR Firewall something like that were blocking firebase download urls.

When connect my macbook with Mobile Network, then it worked, And finally "pod install" command work successfully.

I have informed my Office Network Admin person to fix and allow firebase url https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/bf4dd8c5ac4d8ac9/Firebase-3.10.0.tar.gz from terminal. Hope they will fix this issue asap.

But for the time I have installed successfully firebase pod on Mobile Network. Hope this can solve your problem also.

Answer (score 1):

i am also facing the same problem for installing FCM pods.try to add your        pod files in top like bellow sceen.This is my pod file <`pod 'Firebase/Core',pod 'Firebase/Messaging'>

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, '9.0'

 target 'ChkdIn' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use  dynamic frameworks
 # use_frameworks!

 # Pods for ChkdIn
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
 pod 'CarbonKit'
 pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
 pod 'RKCardView'
 pod 'HTHorizontalSelectionList', '~> 0.7.4'
 pod 'DGActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'ASJTagsView'


target 'ChkdInTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

target 'ChkdInUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

 end
```

Comment: Hi Siva, Have you found any solution for this , the same issue I am facing

Comment: just now i am facing the same issue, just add your pod files like <pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'> in top.

Comment: in my side i added the files in down it is not working then after i added pod files in top it's working.

Comment: but my side it is working, ok can you post your pod file here.

Comment: ok Siva, I set pod 'Firebase/Core' in top , but same issue still exist for me. I am doing it first time , I have set only library in pod file as  pod 'Firebase/Core'

Comment: can you post your pod file here @vnaren001

Comment: @Siva :-  My pod file is as below :------

# Specs Sources List
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Project Configuration
platform :ios, '8.0'

abstract_target 'AbstractTarget' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'

pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.15.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.15.0'

target 'Target1'
target 'Target2'

end

Comment: It may be difficult to read the pod file as comment, so I uploaded an image please see is this accessible to you https://postimg.org/image/5532yxzwh/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only adding

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
```

Add this

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

This fixed issue for me.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update%5C_your%5C_infoplist